# MYSQL error: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, access-denied

When I try to connect to the sql server and enter the following in command prompt:

```
shell> mysql --user=username--password=password db_name
```

I get error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Y
>   ES)

What does this error mean?

Comment: See at [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/777008)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It means your password is wrong or the account "root" has no access to the database on host "localhost".

Look at the right side bar. There are multiple questions equivalent to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a space is missing between username and --password

If you don't know the root password, with Debian or Ubuntu, there is an easy way to reset it :
First, get the exact version of your server using

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep 'mysql-server-'
```

Then, just use sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.x

(btw, replace 5.x with you real version number)

On a fresh install, the default root password is blank, so should be able to log in using just

```
mysql -u root
```

You should obviously add a root password after installation

```
mysqladmin -u root password [newpassword]
```

In most cases, you should also set up dedicated accounts with limited rights before working with a DB.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I upvoted because the `dpkg --get-selections` command was useful and helped me get a little further along.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows -

1. Search for services
2. Stop the service named **MySQL[#]** (in my case it was MySQL80).
3. Start the service again.
4. Open Command Prompt and type:

   > mysql [database name] -u [user name] -p

It worked for me when no other solutions worked. Hope this solves your issue as well.