# MYSQL error: 1045 (28000): Access denied

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

ruby on rails mysql production replication

This project is a cloned repo I want to be able to duplicate the production file for mysql database locally. I can run the application but, I'm  missing a lot of assets. I have listed a few resources about the contents of the application below. Please let me know if I need to add anything else to better help you help me. Thanks

I have taken a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957260/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost).. I ran all of the the commands as root, so I don't think that link applies to this issue.

**.bash_profile**

```
export HUB_test_DB="hub_test"
export HUB_test_USER="hub_test"
export HUB_test_PASS="whatevs"
export HUB_DEV_DB="hub_development"
export HUB_DEV_USER="hub_development"
export HUB_DEV_PASS="whatevs"
```

**Mysql commands**

```
mysql -u root -p THEROOTPASSWORD 28 
CREATE USER 'hub_test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'whatevs';
CREATE USER 'hub_development'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'whatevs';
grant all privileges on hub_test.* to hub_test@localhost;
grant all privileges on hub_development.* to hub_development@localhost; 
flush privileges;
```

The test db isn't really used yet.

**Command to duplicate database**

```
mysql -u $HUB_DEV_USER -p $HUB_DEV_DB < db/backup/production-backup-latest.sql
Mysql> show databases;
```

### Database

-information_schema

- mysql
- performance_schema
- test

  **Users and Privileges**

[image]

Comment: what is the actual error message, it is not the Title is it

Comment: attach screenshot of real error. agreed with @Drew

Comment: you have done a stellar job documenting things (compared to your peers). But you need to describe the servers/locations and the connection strings.  It often comes down to hostnames, and what is in mysql.user table

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are correct ?
Also, the syntax `mysql -u root -p THEROOTPASSWORD 28` seems dangerous to me.  e.g. If password contains an exclamation mark, it will fail. (and btw, avoid putting passwords in files, like .sh scripts)