# How do I set mysql password?

Tags: mysql

I was getting an error trying to log in to mysql with `mysql -u root -p` , it always gave me the error "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". I'm on a Macbook Air running Yosemite.

So, I figured that I'd forgotten my password. It got so frustrating trying to reset it that I uninstalled mysql completely by `sudo rm`ing /usr/local/bin/mysql, and then reinstalling the dmg again from scratch. The installer gave me the gibberish temporary password, I tried logging in with it, and I got the same 1045 error that I've been getting all along. So maybe my first password wasn't wiped somehow . . . ?

I've tried this both with and without running `mysqld` in another terminal window, did not make a difference unfortunately. Any help on how I can just set the root password to whatever I want and log into mysql?

Comment: Did you even try using Google? [`mysql reset root password`](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20reset%20root%20password) leads you directly to the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL error: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957260/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a root password, then you need to use the following command:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p oldpassword newpassword
```

If you are trying to update the password for another user use:

```
$ mysqladmin -u user-name -p oldpassword newpassword
```

If you get a `Access denied` error it may be because you are not running the command as root.

To run a command as root add `sudo` to the **beginning** of the command.

For Example:
To update the password for the **current**, as root use:

```
$ sudo mysqladmin -u root -p oldpassword newpassword
```

To update the password for **another user**, as root use:

```
$ sudo mysqladmin -u user-name -p oldpassword newpassword
```

> Also you might want to look at [mysql_secure_installation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html), it will make your mysql installation more secure, it is recommended that you use it for production servers.

Comment: CJ Apel, has my answer helped you? Do you mind sharing if and how you solved the problem?

Comment: Hey thanks very much for your answer. I think I had done some seriously funky stuff on my system, I ended up using homebrew to uninstall and reinstall mysql from scratch, backed up my databases that I needed first of course, and registered a new password. But your answer is certainly the correct way to go in general

Answer (score 0):

You first need to enter in your MySQL database : then copy and paste the following

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('SETYOURPASSWORDHERE');
```

Be sure your user is `root`